# In HTML, why do I have to add `autofill="new-name"` instead of `autofill="off"` to prevent the browser from autofilling the input?

Tags: html, angular, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete

In my Angular project, I have a form where the user edits another user's profile. I need the inputs to not autofill, naturally, but the browser (I am testing with Chrome 120.0.6099.110) insists on autofilling the form.

I do not have any sort of chrome extension for passwords or such. It is Chrome's built-in autofiller.

I tried to turn off autocomplete on the whole form, as the documentation suggests (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete):

`<form [formGroup]="form.get('profile')" autocomplete="off">`

But the doc does specify that setting this property on the form does not always work.

> Note: In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to "off" will not prevent a password manager from asking the user if they would like to save username and password information, or from automatically filling in those values in a site's login form.

It indeed did not work, so next I tried to turn off autocomplete on my input directly:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname" autocomplete="off">`

Again, not working. What I tried next, following guidance online, is to use `autocomplete="new-name"`

`<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname" autocomplete="new-name">`

This method worked. It seems to be linked to `new-password` that the doc describes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password) but I do not see why it is so hard to turn off autocomplete on an input (or a form as a whole).

Why do I need to put new-name, or basically "new" in my autocomplete property for it to work? I feel like I'm playing a game of fooling the browser, instead of telling it to not autofill my input.

(Edit): And more importantly, is this solution future-proof? I have tried with values like `autocomplete="someRandomThing"` and it works at preventing autofill, but it feels like a bad practice.

Comment: that's just the way they wrote the browser... it used to be worse... you'd have to put in a duplicate hidden input whenever you had a change password field there...  (then the browser would auto-fill that hidden input field instead of the one you needed)  On the bright-side, those stored passwords will be set per user-profile.